# Horror with a decapitated blue head in a chair?

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv, horror

when I was young flipping through the channels on TV, I watched a single scene that scarred me for almost 5 years.  It could be rated R because I was spoiled enough to have satellite as a kid. All I remember...

A small group of people climb into a library (maybe a school library )( which I assume was a basement because the windows were small and only at the top ).  When they got in, they thought they were safe until somebody turned a swivel chair around and there was suddenly a man's decapitated head that was all blue.

If I remember correctly from the image quality it was a late 80s or early 90s film.  People have told me "IT" but I have never seen it and that doesn't make much sense to me.

please help me relive my nightmares!  Thanks!

Edit:  could be a TV series, but it seemed pretty gruesome for tv.  It was around 20 years ago, +/- 5 years in the US.  There were 3-5 people that were between teens to 30s.  The head itself was absolutely all blue not from the lighting.  That image was seared into my brain.

Still haven't found anything and Halloween has made me revisit the idea.  Any help would be appreciated and I will definitely share the answer if i find it.

Comment: `Flipping through channels on TV` Was this in the USA? Or Australia? Or Japan? etc.

Comment: Also, when were you a kid? Two weeks ago? ten years ago? 30?

Comment: Are you sure it was a movie, not a TV series?

Comment: What age(s) are the people in the group? Can you be more precise about the number of people? What did they think they were safe from? Was the head blue or was it (dramatic) lighting?

Comment: Never considered a tv series!  Opened a whole new door to me!

Comment: Was the head blue/black from normal decomposition or blue like it had been painted blue?

Comment: I remember feeling it was blue because the guy had suffocated, so it wasn't paint blue.  However it didn't seem like it decomposed either.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like the movie was "House" from 1986 -scared me to death too. I was only a grade school kid and caught parts of it on TV, and the only reason I even remembered it was the commercials that came on said-we return you to House-and there is a blue head in the chair.

Comment: Full movie is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p_VgQ7JIjes) but I can't see the bit with the head in the chair...

Comment: There was a blue (crystal) skull in the sequel; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jZpnZHhuYnE

Comment: it might be house 2 then. I never saw both films from beginning to end, just enough parts to scare me as a kid.

Comment: Thanks for the help!   Sadly though i didn't see the head in the chair part either.   The crystal skull from the sequel wasn't it either.  It was definitely a man's head, face and all.